# Maintaining large data structure (objects) in function parameters?

Tags: java, scala

To avoid using global variables, I pass the data structure around in some functions.

The data structure is basically a class with several fields of type (mutable) hash map in Scala.

Then I am wondering if those hash maps have more and more large entries (the value in the hash map could be a set of some objects), will it cause stackover flow or out of heap memory?

I suppose it could cause out of heap memory error? since the the class with those hash map fileds is (are) objects, which are allocated on the heap....but space for parameters of a function are  maintained within some frame on the stack...

Of course, for whatever error, the design should make the changing objects being passed around as "small" as possible to avoid memory leak, right?

Thanks for any comment or insights!

Comment: Do you have an *actual* performance problem or are you just idly speculating?

Comment: (More to the point: why are you worrying about highly specific error conditions like a stack overflow or heap exhaustion when you don't really understand the underlying fundamentals of how objects are represented and passed around in the JVM?)

Comment: @millimoose Have encountered both errors before, and now "idly speculating" to the basic questions.

Comment: The basic questions are unrelated to the errors. You'll get a stack overflow because you have a bug that causes infinite recursion. You'll get an out of memory error because you have a memory leak or are working with huge datasets. Passing objects to methods in correct code shouldn't, except in rare cases, cause either of those.

Comment: And while it's fine to want to understand how the JVM works at this level, Stack Overflow is not a teaching site. I don't think questions of the form "explain this fundamental concept to me" are appropriate.

Comment: @millimoose I respectively disagree with your last comment.

Comment: My reasoning is right there [in the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/dont-ask): "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Java and Scala both use **references** not actual **values**.

So what you are passing around is never a copy of your structure but **a copy of a reference to your structure**.

You will need to ask yourself these questions if you work with **.Net**, typically **C#**, because **.Net, like native C++, supports two semantics for object storage: value and reference**.

Comment: Nope, structs in .NET are neither that common or that big for you to have to think about this.